# How to create Firebase Dynamic Links using Maui.iOS?

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, maui, firebase-dynamic-links, maui-ios

I'm using .Net Maui with firebase to create a dynamic link for iOS. The error I'm getting is this one:

"Safari can not open this page because address is invalid"
[Safari's alert](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pHC2V.png)

I entered the team id and created a random app store id, since the app is not deployed on app store. The URL: https://example.page.link/apple-app-site-association, is working just fine.
I added GoogleService-Info.plist in platform directory, iOS folder, just as instructed. I also added apple-app-site-association that looks like this:

```
{
  "applinks": {
    "apps": [],
    "details": [
      {
        "appIDs": [ "TeamID.com.companyname.example"],
        "paths": [ "NOT /_/*", "/*" ]

        
      }
    ]
  },
  "webcredentials": {
    "apps": [ "TeamID.com.companyname.example" ]
  },

  "appclips": {
    "apps": [ "TeamID.com.companyname.example" ]
  }
}
```

I don't know if i missed any step until now. Recently I added Entitlements.plist that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>com.apple.developer.associated-domains</key>
    <array>
        <string>applinks:example.page.link</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

With this I should do some sort of provisioning, but the apple account I have needs to be paid for that to work. Is there some tutorial that I can use for Maui with free provisioning? Or am i headed in the wrong direction? Did I miss a step?

Comment: Does this help? [Free provisioning for Xamarin.iOS apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/get-started/installation/device-provisioning/free-provisioning?tabs=macos)

Comment: I couldn't get it to work using that tutorial

Comment: You could generate a new provisioning file for the app and deploy it on physical device.